# Is it possible to modify an object namespace in a Mutating Webhook?

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a Mutating Webhook for a Namespaced CRD. In this Webhook, I would like to dynamically change the namespace of the resource, no matter what the user specified.

When I try to create a resource, I get the following error:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "crd.yaml": the namespace of the provided object does not match the namespace sent on the request
```

Is it possible to perform this change and, if so, am I missing any configuration?

Comment: Could you share more information to help troubleshoot the issue? Which namespace does the original manifest specify? How does the code for your webhook looks like?  

Furthermore - it looks, from the log you've attached, that the webhook might be trying to change the namespace for the CRD, and not the CR. CRDs are not namespaced object, even if the CR they are creating is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it might not be possible: looking at the code [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/registry/rest/create.go#L108), you can see that if the resource you're attempting to create already has a namespace (the request), and your webhook attempts to mutate the object to replace the namespace (the object), then there will be a mismatch.

```
    if err := EnsureObjectNamespaceMatchesRequestNamespace(ExpectedNamespaceForScope(requestNamespace, strategy.NamespaceScoped()), objectMeta); err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

You can see that the function `EnsureObjectNamespaceMatchesRequestNamespace` takes in two things: the expected namespace from the request and the object's metadata. If the request coming in is namespaced, then the request's namespace will be returned.

If you look at the function, you can see that your case falls through to the default case:

```
    switch {
    case objNamespace == requestNamespace:
        // already matches, no-op
        return nil

    case objNamespace == metav1.NamespaceNone:
        // unset, default to request namespace
        obj.SetNamespace(requestNamespace)
        return nil

    case requestNamespace == metav1.NamespaceNone:
        // cluster-scoped, clear namespace
        obj.SetNamespace(metav1.NamespaceNone)
        return nil

    default:
        // mismatch, error
        return errors.NewBadRequest("the namespace of the provided object does not match the namespace sent on the request")
    }
```

Did you end up figuring out a workaround for yourself?

Comment: I couldn't find any other solution. I reworked the solution so that namespace modification is not required. Thank you for your input!